# How to convert stream of bytes to UTF-8 characters?

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding

I need to convert a stream of bytes to a line of UTF-8 characters. The only character that is important for me in that line is the last one. And this conversion should happen in a cycle, so the performance is very important. A simple and inefficient approach would be:

```
public class Foo {
  private ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  void next(byte input) {
    this.buffer.write(input);
    String text = this.buffer.toString("UTF-8"); // this is time consuming
    if (text.charAt(text.length() - 1) == THE_CHAR_WE_ARE_WAITING_FOR) {
      System.out.println("hurray!");
      this.buffer.reset();
    }   
  }
}
```

Conversion of byte array to string happens on every input byte, which is, in my understanding, very ineffective. Is it possible to do it somehow else to preserve the results of bytes-to-text conversion from a previous cycle?

Comment: I'm missing something here. How can you convert single bytes, when UTF-8 text uses more than one byte per character?

Comment: That's why I need a `ByteArrayOutputStream` that does this conversion job

Comment: Why not use an InputStreamReader?

Comment: But you're still only reading single bytes. The string conversion might even fail on incomplete characters/

Comment: Because there is no stream to read, as you see in the example

Comment: So where is the data coming from?

Comment: InputStreamReader can wrap any other stream--doesn't have to be a file, could be a stream from a string or from memory.

Comment: Like so:     InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new InputStream() {
   @Override
   public int read() throws IOException {
    return // wherever you get your data from.
   }
  });
  while(true) {
   try {
    if(isr.read() == THE_CHAR_WE_ARE_WAITING_FOR)
     System.out.println("hurray!");
   } catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }

Comment: In my case order of control is the opposite. I can't wait for bytes, they are injected into my class by data provider

Comment: @yegor256: What is the code point you are interested in exactly? Is it something simple as a codepoint below 128? Or (on the other extreme) something like a surrogate character?

Comment: It's line feed (`0x0A`)

Comment: Then it's trivially simple.  Just wait for the linefeed character.  Since that is in the 7 bit ascii range, you don't have to do any utf-8 fanciness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment:

> It's line feed (0x0A)

Your `next` method can just check:

```
if ((char)input == THE_CHAR_WE_ARE_WAITING_FOR) {
    //whatever your logic is.
}
```

You don't have to do any conversion for characters < 128.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a simple class to keep track of the characters, and only convert when you got a full UTF8 sequence. Here's a sample (with no error checking which you may want to add)

```
class UTF8Processor {
    private byte[] buffer = new byte[6];
    private int count = 0;

    public String processByte(byte nextByte) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        buffer[count++] = nextByte;
        if(count == expectedBytes())
        {
            String result = new String(buffer, 0, count, "UTF-8");
            count = 0;
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private int expectedBytes() {
        int num = buffer[0] & 255;
        if(num < 0x80) return 1;
        if(num < 0xe0) return 2;
        if(num < 0xf0) return 3;
        if(num < 0xf8) return 4;
        return 5;
    }
}

class Bop
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // Create test data.
        String str = "Hejsan åäö/漢ya";
        byte[] bytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");

        String ch;

        // Processes byte by byte, returns a valid UTF8 char when 
        //there is a complete one to get.

        UTF8Processor processor = new UTF8Processor();

        for(int i=0; i<bytes.length; i++)
        {
            if((ch = processor.processByte(bytes[i])) != null)
                System.out.println(ch);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should call reset() from inside processByte() - there is no good reason to require the buffer to be managed externally.

Comment: @Clyde True, not the cleanest code since it was thrown together in a  few minutes. I'll fix that though.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- If the codepoint you are interested in is something simple (in UTF-8 terms) as a codepoint below 128, then a simple cast from `byte` to `char` is possible. Lookup the encoding rules on [Wikipadia: UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) for the reason why this works.
- If this is not possible, you can take a look at the `Charset` class which is the root of Java's encoding/decoding library. Here you will find `CharsetDecoder` which you can feed N bytes and get back M characters. The general case is N != M . However you will have to deal with `ByteBuffer` and `CharBuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your byte-getting code in an InputStream and pass that to an InputStreamReader.

```
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new InputStream() {
        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return xx();// wherever you get your data from.
        }
    }, "UTF-8");
    while(true) {
        try {
            if(isr.read() == THE_CHAR_WE_ARE_WAITING_FOR)
                System.out.println("hurray!");
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: See the update to my question. I can't wait for bytes.. They are injected into my class from somewhere else. In other words, I can't stay and wait for the next byte, like in your example

Comment: @yegor256 The question as you have now edited it is fundamentally different to the original question. The two options for your edited question are to use InputStreamReader with a dedicated thread to wait for the data, or to implement a stateful UTF-8 decoder. The length of a UTF-8 sequence is a maximum of 4 and the length can be determined by examining the first byte. Once each sequence has been examined you can discard it, rather than buffering up the whole input stream as your code does (which as you realised is inefficient.)